# inverse of function that has $\epsilon x$ and $\operatorname{sign}(x)$

Tags: inverse-function, neural-networks

Reading ["Recurrent Experience Replay in Distributed Reinforcement Learning"](https://openreview.net/forum?id=r1lyTjAqYX) paper, the authors use the function $h$ which can re-scale the q-estimates the network receives.

The authors say $h$ is an invertable function, but I can't even get past first step of inverting it.

$$h(x) = \operatorname{sign}(x)(\sqrt{|x|+1} -1) + \epsilon x$$
where $\epsilon$ is a very small number, for example $0.0001$ and $x$ is any real number.

The first step of finding $h^{-1}$, is to swap it with its argument:

$$x =\operatorname{sign}(h)(\sqrt{|h|+1} -1) + \epsilon h$$

But then, how do I re-arrange it to  express it in terms of $x$ once again?

---

paper name: [Recurrent Experience Replay in Distributed Reinforcement Learning](https://openreview.net/forum?id=r1lyTjAqYX), page 3

---

**Edit 1** (edit removed)

**Edit 2**
As @dcolazin answer shows, re-arrange the original equation into:

$$\epsilon^2 X^2 -(2\epsilon(H+1)+1)X + (H+1)^2-1=0$$

Now that it's in the form of $at^2 + bt + c =0$ we can apply the discriminant rule, to get 2 expressions:

$$t_{1,2} = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

Taking the above equation, we get

$$X_{1,2} =\frac{2\epsilon H + 2\epsilon + 1 \pm \sqrt{4\epsilon^2 + 4\epsilon H + 4\epsilon + 1}}{2\epsilon^2}$$

applying the $sign_x = sign_h$ and $x = sign_xX$ trick, we get:

$$x = \frac{sign_x \cdot \bigg( 2\epsilon |h| + 2\epsilon + 1 \pm \sqrt{4\epsilon(\epsilon + |h| + 1) + 1}\bigg) }{2\epsilon^2}$$

in other words,

$$h^{-1}_x = \frac{sign_h \cdot \bigg( 2\epsilon |h_x| + 2\epsilon + 1 \pm 2 \sqrt{\epsilon(\epsilon + |h_x| + 1) + 0.25}\bigg) }{2\epsilon^2}$$

simplifying further:

$$h^{-1}_x = \frac{sign_h \cdot \bigg( \epsilon |h_x| + \epsilon + 0.5 \pm  \sqrt{\epsilon(\epsilon + |h_x| + 1) + 0.25}\bigg) }{\epsilon^2}$$

notice $\pm$

**Edit 3**
Somehow, plotting my function doesn't appear on the graph, and plotting the function of @dcolazin looks like a straight line.

Instead, I would expect them to curve-upwards, cancelling out the effect of $h$

[image]

---

**Edit 4 (conclusion)**

As was pointed out in the comment below by @dcolazin, the inverse function should have just a usual argument.  So, renaming things, we get:

$$h^{-1} = \frac{sign_x \cdot \bigg( \epsilon |x| + \epsilon + 0.5 -  \sqrt{\epsilon(\epsilon + |x| + 1) + 0.25}\bigg) }{\epsilon^2}$$

This is the final inverse function, which takes into the account epsilon. However, as @dcolazin has shown, if epsilon is negligible you should use the version he told, since it's more performant on hardware:

$$h^{-1} \approx sign_x \cdot \frac{(|x|+1)^2-1}{2\epsilon(|x|+1)+1}$$

Where $sign_x$ is of course $\frac{x}{|x|}$ which is either 1 or -1

Comment: if $y$ is the composition of $h$ and its inverse, it should look like a line because it is the identity!

Comment: Got it! added Edit 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me call $s_x, s_h$ the sign of $x,h$.

$$h = s_x(\sqrt{|x| +1 } -1) + \epsilon x$$

Then $$s_x = s_h \Rightarrow s_h h = s_x (s_x(\sqrt{|x| +1 } -1) + \epsilon x) \Rightarrow \\ |h| = \sqrt{|x| +1 } -1 + \epsilon |x| \Rightarrow |h|+1 = \sqrt{|x| +1 } + \epsilon |x|$$

$$|h|+1-\epsilon |x| = \sqrt{|x|+1} \Rightarrow (|h|+1-\epsilon |x|)^2 = |x|+1 \Rightarrow$$

$$(|h|+1)^2 + \epsilon^2 x^2 - 2\epsilon(|h|+1)|x| = |x|+1 \Rightarrow$$

Call $X=|x|, H = |h|$:

$$\epsilon^2 X^2 -(2\epsilon(H+1)+1)X + (H+1)^2-1=0 \Rightarrow$$

is a second degree equation that you can resolve. Remember that $s_x = s_h$ and you can find $x = s_xX$.

But if $\epsilon^2$ is trascurable, then $X \sim \frac{(H+1)^2-1}{2\epsilon(H+1)+1}$.

Comment: Thank you! Could you give me a hint why $s_x = s_h$ ? Also, with your help I've posted the resolved version in the edit to my question, in case anyone is looking for a quick reference. Does it look correct?

Comment: @Kari $s_x = s_h$ because $h = s_x(\text{positive number}) + \epsilon x = s_x(\ldots) + s_x \epsilon |x|$

Comment: @Kari also: what you did in your edit? You have to resolve the second degree equation for $X$ and only one solution should be admissible

Comment: I've edited my question, to show what I ended-up with. Somehow I can't see how by making $\epsilon$ negligible we would end up with $|x| \sim \frac{(|h_x|+1)^2-1}{2\epsilon(|h_x|+1)+1}$. Could you please help me see it?

Comment: Also, by applying a discriminant rule, I get 2 versions (because of $\pm$ sign). As you said, one solution should be admissible - which of the 2 versions do I pick, and why? What would the other version do, were I to use it as the inverse? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, the graphs are now curving correctly, both versions look good.  However, I actually had to use the "$-$" solution of discriminant. The + version doesn't look like an inverse, but the "minus" version is exactly the inverse, perfectly matching your version (for trascurable $\epsilon^2$) when $\epsilon$ is close to $0$. I've shown it in my final edit.

Comment: @Kari yeah, I was wrong, the "$-$" solution is the correct one!